# Extension methods for two different classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, odata, extension-methods

I have a situation where in C# I consume data via an OData API. Actually, there are two different OData endpoints (two different models), where one is a superset of the other.

I have created two different C# projects (A and B) which contain code to interact with the two API's. The code is automatically generated using [Unchase OData Connected Service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unchase.unchaseodataconnectedservice). As a result, project A and project B both contain a class `ODataService`, which is the main type to interact with. Depending on whether I need the full API or the reduced API, I reference project A or B correspondingly.

I would like to write extension methods for the `ODataService` class in a seperate project C, such that I can use these extension methods no matter if I choose to reference project A (full API) or project B (reduced API).

What would be a good approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

1. Create an interface for `ODataService`-s (e.g.: `IODataService`)
2. Create partial classes for your services that implement the interface:
   (e.g.: `public partial class ODataService1: IODataService {...}`)
3. Create the extension methods for the `IODataService`

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but I'm not sure I fully understand the suggestion. They ODataService classes are already partial, and are generated by a tool. Further, they themselves inherit from DataServiceContext. Are you suggesting that I modify  the ODataService classes by hand?

Comment: If the generated classes are already partial ones, then no need of modifying, just create another partial class with exactly the same name and derive it from your newly created interface. But if the generated classes are not partial, then - yes, you might need to modify.

Comment: Hi @JustShadow - thanks again, I will try. Should the IODataService interface and partial class ODataService, that I put in project C, be put in the same namespace as the other two auto generated partial classes?

Comment: Well, that will work as well. Alternatively you can have a different namespace for the interface, but then you'll need to include the namespace to the partial class's files (with "using")

Comment: Hi @JustShadow. Sorry, but I just can't seem to make it work. The setup is as follows. Project A and Project B contain References.cs, which define dozens of partial classes that all (most?) inherit from some other class. One of them is ODataService, which inherits from DataServiceContext. In Project C I want to define a range of extension methods for those parts that A and B have in common. But I need to do that without Project C referencing A nor B, such that when in Project D, I reference e.g. A+C or B+C, everything turns out to work magically.