# Inheritance from two swappable class libraries

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

### C# solution structure

- Project `ApiReduced`: A class library containing a file `Reference.cs` generated by a tool. It contains dozens of partial classes, most of which inherit from another .NET class, e.g. the class `ODataService` inherits from `DataServiceContext`. The classes are all in the same namespace `Som`.
- Project `ApiFull`: Class library same as `ApiReduced`, but contains more partial classes, classes have further properties, etc. Think of it as a superset of `ApiReduced`. Again, under the same namespace `Som`.
- Project `ApiExtensions`: Contains `Extensions.cs`, which should either (not yet decided if inheritance or extension methods make most sense)

  - inherit from **either** of the `ODataService` classes or
  - provide extension methods for the classes in **either** project `ApiReduced` or `ApiFull`
- Project `MyProject`: Contains code that references **either** project `ApiReduced` **or** `ApiFull`. Furthermore, it references `ApiExtensions`.

### Desired effect

What I want to accomplish with the above is to be able to decide in `MyProject` what API to use (full or reduced), depending on whether I add a reference to `ApiReduced` or `ApiFull`. In reality I have several projects, some should use the full API, some the reduced API, but I want to be able to use the same extensions in either case to avoid code duplication.

### What I've tried

When in `ApiExtensions` I reference both `ApiReduced` and `ApiFull`, I naturally get a lot of errors that the types defined in `Reference.cs` exists in both libraries. On the other hand, how can I implement `Extensions.cs` without referencing at least one of `ApiReduced` or `ApiFull`? And if I make a choice, that seems rather arbitrary.

### TL;DR

How can I swap between using two nearly identical class libraries (in the sense they define partial classes with the same names in same namespace) for my extension methods/derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Interfaces and dependency injection!

---

Any behaviour you want to add an extension to should be based on an interface, and then you implement that interface in both your Full & Reduced api classes. Your extensions assembly should *only* reference the interfaces assembly and add extensions as appropriate. At this point your assemblies look like

- ApiFull (references ApiInterfaces)
- ApiReduced (references ApiInterfaces)
- ApiExtensions (references ApiInterfaces)
- ApiInterfaces
- MyProject (references ApiExtensions, ApiInterfaces and either ApiFull or ApiReduced)

Then in your project you again only code against interfaces, and in that way you can use the extensions as necessary. In this project, you use Dependency Injection to inject the correct concrete class (from either ApiFull or ApiReduced)

---

No answer is complete without a code sample. So, adding extensions to interfaces:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.SayHello());
    }
}

public static class INamedExtensions
{
    public static string SayHello(this INamed named)
    {
        return $"Hello from {named.Name}";
    }       
}


public class Foo : INamed 
{
    public string Name {get => "Foo";}
}

public interface INamed 
{
    string Name{get;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand you correctly, each class in `Reference.cs` has to inherit from a corresponding interface, which I must define? The issue is, for the full API, the `Reference.cs` file has 300.000 lines of code and hundreds of classes. It would be a huge job to maintain all those interfaces without an automated approach.

Comment: It sounds like that is a kind of "repository" layer, and I would personally be wrapping this in a "Service" layer which contains my logic/interface(s) for my app. I think what you're missing here is just the way large apps are put together.

Comment: Also note that [when you asked a very similar question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106014/extension-methods-for-two-different-classes) you got much the same answer!

Comment: Hi @Jamiec. I didn't mean to devaluate your answer. It was more a question of clarification: For each class `ClassX` I want to extend, I need to modify the auto-generated class to inherit from a new interface `IClassX` which defines the properties and methods from `ClassX` that I want to use in my extensions? It might not be so bad after all, since I'm only extending a part of the actual classes.

Comment: @mmlschadegg You said they were partial - the reason automated tools generate partial classes is so you can build on them without having to edit the generated code. Just write in a separate file `public partial class ClassX : IMyInterface {}` and you should be all good.

Comment: I started implementing the approach suggested. However, I get stuck pretty early. Probably I'm missing something. In `ApiExtensions` I want to use `ClassX`, so I put in `ApiInterfaces` the following `public partial class ClassX : IClassX`. Now, in `ApiExtensions` I want to access `PropY` of `ClassX`, but it is unknown, so I define the property in the `IClassX` interface. But now `ApiInterfaces` can't compile, because `partial class ClassX` does not implement it (it is implemented in `ApiReduced`, `ApiFull` or both).

Comment: @mmlschadegg only the interface itself should be in ApiInterfaces. Your partial classes should be in  ApiFull or ApiReduced as necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226096/discussion-between-jamiec-and-mmlschadegg).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split your Extensions into `ApiReducedExtensions` and `ApiFullExtensions`.

That way, when you want to use the Reduced API in a project you include `ApiReduced` and `ApiReducedExtensions`

And when you want to use only the FullApi, you only include `ApiFull` and `ApiFullExtensions`

### Edit

To avoid duplicated code between the two you can add another class `ApiSharedExtensions` which contains the code both have in common. Same for the Api

Comment: And how does that avoid duplication of code between `ApiFullExtensions` and `ApiReducedExtensions`?